# Pandas add increment index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have the following Pandas DataFrame

```
Key Value 
A    10
A    20
B    30
B    40
C    50
A    60
A    70
A    70
B    80
A    90
```

And I need to create an index that auto increment only when the key repeats after sequence of different keys. So, I need this output:

```
Key Value Index
A    10     1
A    20     1
B    30     1
B    40     1
C    50     1
A    60     2
A    70     2
A    70     2
B    80     2
A    90     3
```

Thanks!

I try with the method `groupby` and `cumcount() + 1` but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an ordered Categorical and [`numpy.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html):

```
import numpy as np

s = pd.Categorical(df['Key'], ordered=True)
df['Index'] = np.cumsum(s<s.shift())+1
```

*If you want a custom order pass `categories=['X', 'Z', 'Y']`.*

Or, like @SimonT commented, if your categories are lexicographically sorted:

```
df['Index'] = np.cumsum(df['Key']<df['Key'].shift())+1
```

Output:

```
  Key  Value  Index
0   A     10      1
1   A     20      1
2   B     30      1
3   B     40      1
4   C     50      1
5   A     60      2
6   A     70      2
7   A     70      2
8   B     80      2
9   A     90      3
```

Comment: Yea much neater and has the numpy optimisation :) I didn't use numpy since OP didn't mention it.

Comment: @SimonT yes because of the lexicographic order. With a Categorical you can choose a custom order ;)

Comment: If I had to do the operation based on two columns? not only for column KEY, but KEYA and KEYB

Comment: Difficult to give an exact answer without example of the exact wanted logic but something like `np.cumsum((s1<s1.shift())&(s2<s2.shift()))+1` or setting the categories as columns and using `any`/`all`.

Answer (score 4):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Key': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A'],
    'Value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 70, 80, 90]
})

df['Index'] = (df.Key != df.Key.shift()).cumsum()
df['Index'] = df.groupby('Key')['Index'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)

display(df)



Key Value   Index
0   A   10  1
1   A   20  1
2   B   30  1
3   B   40  1
4   C   50  1
5   A   60  2
6   A   70  2
7   A   70  2
8   B   80  2
9   A   90  3
```

A quick breakdown of what is going on

```
# checks whether the current Key is not equal to the last Key, returning a boolean series.
# The cumsum function then returns the cumulative sum of this series, which gives you the unique key for each group that you requested. 

df.Key != df.Key.shift().cumsum()


# The below ranks these numbers by each Key group, which gives each unique number within a group the same rank.

groupby('Key')['Index'].rank(method='dense')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to calculate dense rank using [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html)

```
df['Index'] = (df['Key'] != df['Key'].shift()).cumsum()
df['Index'] = df.groupby('Key')['Index'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0] + 1)
```

---

**Output:**

```
  Key  Value  Index
0   A     10      1
1   A     20      1
2   B     30      1
3   B     40      1
4   C     50      1
5   A     60      2
6   A     70      2
7   A     70      2
8   B     80      2
9   A     90      3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['Key'].ne(df['Key'].shift()).groupby(df['Key']).cumsum()
```

or

```
df.loc[df['Key'].ne(df['Key'].shift())].groupby('Key').cumcount().add(1).reindex(df.index,method = 'ffill')
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    2
7    2
8    2
9    3
```